# Ignoring escape sequences and other characters in UNIX redirection

Tags: unix, redirect, terminal, console

I'm redirecting console output to a file, and getting `[?25h` and `[?25l` mixed in with my regular output. I've looked online and [apparently](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf) they are the sequence characters for cnorm and civis, whatever those are. Is there any way to suppress these in the output?

Comment: maybe pipe through sed first?

Comment: A terminal is a scripting environment and questions regarding them and their behavior are on topic for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up piping through sed. Jim's info is still very helpful, though. I used this command:

```
sed 's/\[?25[hl]//'
```

Incidentally, it catches `[?25h` and `[?25l`, but not when they're in succession (`[?25h[?25l`). Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Use the `g` ("global") flag to `sed`, to make sure multiple occurrences on the same line get replaced:  `sed 's/\[?25[hl]//g'`

Comment: If you want to see the output as you pipe (e.g. not when the program finishes) you have to use the `-u` flag (unbuffered) as in `sed -u 's/\[?25[hl]//g'`

Answer (score 2):

One thing you might try is to set the TERM environment variable to something
that doesn't support those features, for example with a Bash command like this:

```
env TERM=dumb yourcmd > yourfile
```

(Where `yourcmd` is the program whose output you'd like to redirect to output file `yourfile`)

For other shells, you might have to do something more like

```
setenv TERM dumb
yourcmd > yourfile
```

Comment: Looks intriguing. How would I figure out what my "yourcmd" variable is?

Comment: "yourcmd" is supposed to be replaced with whatever program you're using and want to redirect to a file.  In Bash, this syntax lets you run a command in a modified environment.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe the program doesn't bother checking the TERM variable, and just assumes it's something common, like xterm or vt100, that supports those escape sequences.  In that case, you might be stuck having to pipe the output through `sed` to remove the undesired sequences.  Hopefully it only uses a few distinct sequences, otherwise the sed part might get ugly.